# Socket program need an integer

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, tkinter

I have a chat client and but when I run it I get an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Programming\Chat Client\Chat Client.py", line 21, in
<module>
    s = socket.socket((socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python33\lib\socket.py", line 94, in __init__
    _socket.socket.__init__(self, family, type, proto, fileno)
TypeError: an integer is required
```

I don't know what this means so can anyone please help me?

Here is my programs code:

```
# Import Modules
from tkinter import *
from socket import *
from threading import *

# Window Setup
root = Tk()
root.title('Chat Client')
root.state('zoomed')

# Chat Variables
global s
s = socket.socket((socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM))
s.connect((TARGET, DEFAULT_PORT))

enter = StringVar()
TARGET = s.gethostname()
DEFAULT_PORT = 45000

# Chat Message Box Setup
chat = Text(root, height=31, state=DISABLED)
entry = Entry(root, fg='blue', textvariable=enter, width=200)
scroll = Scrollbar(root)

chat['yscrollcommand'] = scroll.set
scroll['command'] = chat.yview

scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
chat.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
entry.pack(side=BOTTOM)

# Send Command
def send(event):
    msg = enter.get()
    chat['state'] = NORMAL
    chat['fg'] = 'blue'
    chat.insert(END, ('You: ' + msg + '\n'))
    while 1:
        s.sendall(msg)
    chat['state'] = DISABLED
    chat['fg'] = 'black'
    enter.set('')
    s.close()

    entry.bind('<Return>', send)

def recieve(): 
    s.bind((TARGET, DEFAULT_PORT))
    s.listen(True)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
    chat['state'] = NORMAL
    chat['fg'] = 'red'
    chat.insert(END, ('Stranger: ' + data + '\n'))

thread.start(recieve, ())
thread.start(send, ())

root.mainloop()
```

So could anyone please help me with this as I don't know what I need to do with my code to fix this. Any Ideas?

Thanks In Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing a `tuple` object, `(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)`. You need to pass them as separate arguments: `socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)`. `socket.AF_INET` and `socket.SOCK_STREAM` contain the integer values of 2 and 1, respectively.